# extract strings from a text file distinguishing cases using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have morphologically analyzed documents in this form:

```
^Thus/Thus[ADV]+ADV$ ^an/an[ART]$ ^agnostic/agnostic[ADJ]+ADJ$ 
^is/be[V]+V+3sg+PRES$ ^someone/someone[PN]+INDEF$ ^who/who[PN]+WH$ 
^believes/believe[V]+V+3sg+PRES$ ^that/that[CNJ]+THAT$ ^we/we[PN]+PERS$ 
^do/do[V]+V+INF$ ^not/not[PART]$ ^and/and[CNJ]+COORD$ ^cannot/*cannot$ 
^know/know[V]+V$ ^for/for[PRP]$
^prove/prove[V]+V+INF$ ^that/that[CNJ]+THAT$ ^he/he[PN]+PERS$     
^doesn/*doesn$^'t/it[PN]+PERS$ ^exist/exist[V]+V+INF$
^I'/i'[V]+V$^ve/ve[V]+V+INF$
^didn/didn[V]+V$^'t/it[PN]+PERS$
^can/can[V]+V+INF$^'t/it[PN]+PERS$
```

(Case1) Most of the words get analyzed correctly, like:

```
is --> ^is/be[V]+V+3sg+PRES$
```

(Case2) Some words do not get recognized, like:

```
cannot --> ^cannot/*cannot$
```

(Case3) And all the 'connected' words (doesn't, can't..) get processed like this:

```
doesn't --> ^doesn/*doesn$^'t/it[PN]+PERS$
I've --> ^I'/i'[V]+V$^ve/ve[V]+V+INF$
didn't --> ^didn/didn[V]+V$^'t/it[PN]+PERS$
can't --> ^can/can[V]+V+INF$^'t/it[PN]+PERS$
```

I want to create a new document containing:

- The word between `/` and `[` for Case1
- The word between `^` and `/` or `*` and `$` for Case2
- for Case3 I'm not sure what I want, as the processed form sucks most of the times (from linguistic point of view).. I thought about just taking the beginning between `^` and `/`, as most of the time I will know from the weird word where it came from..

So some sed awk (the only two I know, would be happy if it's possible) script, which splits all strings into analyzing units and then process it for Case1 as standard. If the string contains a single qoute `'` process like Case3, and if it contains a star `*` like Case2. The order is important, as some cases contain `*` and `'`, then Case3 should be applied.

I have absolutely no clue, how to start this, so I have no code to get you started..

Other suggestions for Case3 are welcome, too.

Hope somebody can help!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

So it should look like this:

```
Thus an agnostic be someone who believe that we do not and cannot know 
for prove that he doesn exist I' didn can
```

Comment: Please show some expected output.

Comment: These links can help you to start learning [awk](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_toc.html) and [sed](http://polymer.bu.edu/~fding/sedawk/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you always pick the word between `^`and `/`:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/\^|\/[^\$]+\$/,"")' foo
Thus an agnostic
is someone who
believes that we
do not and cannot
know for
prove that he
doesn't exist
I've
didn't
can't
```

Comment: you have unwanted strings in output: 
"i' ve" should be just i'

Comment: @Matt Pfft, in some prehistoric version... :D

Comment: thats the text i want to analyze morphologically, i already have that

Answer (score 0):

With sed, I guess you could do this:

```
sed -r "s#[^/]+/\*?(\w+'?)\S*\\$ ?#\1 #g" foo
```